# Count how many customers have 1 service , how many customers have 2 services

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

I have this table

```
id_cliente | serv_cuidpess | serv_ali | serv_hab | serv_roupa

125       | 1              | 2        | 1        | 1  
126       | 2              | 1        | 2        | 1
```

which means id_cliente = customerID , and the others serv_ = services where 1 = customer has that service , 2 = he hasn't.

What I'm trying to achieve is counting how many customers have 1 service , how many customers have 2 services , how many customers have 3 services and so on.. I'm using PHP / MySQL

Comment: could you please outline the expected result in tabular form that would be easy for visualization.

Comment: My expected result would be 10 clients have 1 service , 5 clients have 2 services .. and so on. (Note that 2 means NO service).

Comment: its not clear could you elaborate a bit say from above table what you expect in the output.

Comment: The Output should show how many clients have 1 services , how many clients have 2 services , how many cients have 3 services . For example , In the data above I entered the output should be: 1 Client has 3 services and 1 client has 2 services (The value 1 in the MySQL  table means he has that services , 2 means he hasn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for, there 2 cases

Get the total services being taken when its = 1 per customer.

Get the count of customers per service when its = 1

With the above you can try the following query, however its always better to provide more information on the expected output in the question.

**For the first case you can do something as**

```
select
s.id_cliente,
sum(s1.ser1+s1.ser2+s1.ser3+s1.ser4) as tot_services
from services s
inner join
(
  select
  id_cliente,
  case  when serv_cuidpess = 1 then 1 else 0 end as ser1,
  case  when serv_ali = 1 then 1 else 0 end as ser2,
  case  when serv_hab = 1 then 1 else 0 end as ser3,
  case  when serv_roupa = 1 then 1 else 0 end  as ser4
  from services 


)s1 on s1.id_cliente = s.id_cliente
group by s.id_cliente;
```

**For the 2nd case you can do something as**

```
select
serv1_client_count,
serv2_client_count,
serv3_client_count,
serv4_client_count
from services s
inner join
(
  select 
  s1.id_cliente,
  sum(s2.ser1) as serv1_client_count,
  sum(s2.ser2) as serv2_client_count,
  sum(s2.ser3) as serv3_client_count,
  sum(s2.ser4) as serv4_client_count
  from services s1
  inner join
  (
    select
    id_cliente,
    case  when serv_cuidpess = 1 then 1 else 0 end as ser1,
    case  when serv_ali = 1 then 1 else 0 end as ser2,
    case  when serv_hab = 1 then 1 else 0 end as ser3,
    case  when serv_roupa = 1 then 1 else 0 end  as ser4
    from services 
  )s2 on  s2.id_cliente = s1.id_cliente
)t on t.id_cliente = s.id_cliente
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fe57/1)**

**UPDATE**

From the comment

> The Output should show how many have 1 service not service 1.. How
>   many have 2 services not service 2

Here is what you can do

```
select
sum(client_count) as client_count,
serv_count
from services s
inner join
(
  select 
  s1.id_cliente,
  1 as client_count,
  sum(s2.ser1+s2.ser2+s2.ser3+s2.ser4) as serv_count
  from services s1
  inner join
  (
    select
    id_cliente,
    case  when serv_cuidpess = 1 then 1 else 0 end as ser1,
    case  when serv_ali = 1 then 1 else 0 end as ser2,
    case  when serv_hab = 1 then 1 else 0 end as ser3,
    case  when serv_roupa = 1 then 1 else 0 end  as ser4
    from services 
  )s2 on  s2.id_cliente = s1.id_cliente
  group by s1.id_cliente
)t on t.id_cliente = s.id_cliente
group by serv_count
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fe57/15)**

Comment: Yes , It's the first case I'm expecting. But I want the output to COUNT how many customers have 1 service , how many customers have 2 services, how many customers have 3 services . In your first case the output is for each customer how many service he has . Now I want to GROUP(?) customers that have 1 service, customers that have 2 ando so on..

Comment: well thats the 2nd query I have which is doing exactly the same i.e. counting how may customer has service1, how many has service2 and so on.

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining myself properly...The Output should show  how many have 1 service not service 1.. 
How many have 2 services not service 2..

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted ! thank you so much. I don't have enough reputation to vote you up . But i will get it , and come her to vote you! thank you so much once again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned serv_ as processes , I assume that all these`(serv_cuidpess + serv_ali + serv_hab + serv_roupa )` form as processes.

To have the sum you can directly add columns with `+` operator `HAVING`clause is for filtering virtual columns , i.e TotalProcess

Try the below query

```
 select COUNT(id_cliente) AS NoOfUsers,(serv_cuidpess + serv_ali + serv_hab + serv_roupa ) as TotalProcess from PROCESSTABLE GROUP BY TotalProcess HAVING TotalProcess > 0;
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by processes. serv_cuidpess , serv_hab are simple columns in a MySQL table (int). The customer who have laundry (serv_roupa) for example has a 1 in that column and if he hasn't has a 2